# How to get estimate time in FFmpeg using php?

Tags: php, laravel-5, ffmpeg

I'm using FFmpeg for in my project to overlay a video using php.

I have been included a queue for command execute. So, sometimes many requests in queue, and take a long time to execute.

That's why, I have to show the progress bar for user identifies, how many time will take for creates it video. For this scenario, I have to take estimate time.

Maybe it's possible to calculate it by other params that are shown in the output such as fps, bitrate or speed.

Any ideas?

```
 //DownloadJob.php;

 public function __construct($video,$transparent_img,$output_file)
  {
    $this->video=$video;
    $this->transparent_img = $transparent_img;
    $this->output_file = $output_file;
    $create_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $this->status =0;
    $this->download_id = base64_encode($video);

    DB::beginTransaction();
    DB::insert('INSERT INTO jobs_download(download_id,image,video,status,output_video,create_time)
                VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)',[$this->download_id,$this->video,$this->transparent_img,$this->status,$this->output_file,$create_at]);
    DB::commit();
}

public function handle()
{
    $video=$this->video;
    $transparent_img=$this->transparent_img;
    $output_file=$this->output_file;
    $ready=1;
    $failed=2;

    $input_video = $video;
    $transparent_img = $transparent_img;

    try{
        $ffmpeg = "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg";
        $cmd = $ffmpeg . " -i " . $input_video . " -i " . $transparent_img . " -filter_complex 'overlay' " . $output_file;
        //Log::info($cmd);
        exec($cmd, $output);

        if(file_exists($output_file)){

            DB::beginTransaction();
            DB::update('UPDATE jobs_download SET status=? WHERE download_id =?',[$ready,$this->download_id]);
            $this->status = 1;
            DB::commit();

            if(file_exists($input_video)){
                unlink($input_video);
            }

            if(file_exists($transparent_img)){
                unlink($transparent_img);
            }

        }else{
            Log::error('DownloadJob.php failed()',['download_id'=>$this->download_id]);
            DB::beginTransaction();
            DB::update('UPDATE jobs_download SET status=? WHERE download_id =? ',[$failed,$this->download_id]);
            $this->status = 3;
            DB::commit();
        }
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        Log::error('DownloadJob.php failed()',['download_id'=>$this->download_id]);
        DB::beginTransaction();
        DB::update('UPDATE jobs_download SET status=? WHERE download_id =? ',[$failed,$this->download_id]);
        $this->status = 3;
        DB::commit();
    }
}

public function failed()
{
    $failed = 2;
    Log::error('DownloadJob.php failed()',['download_id'=>$this->download_id]);
    DB::beginTransaction();
    DB::update('UPDATE jobs_download SET status=? WHERE download_id =? ',[$failed,$this->download_id]);
    $this->status = 3;
    DB::commit();
}

public function getResponse()
{
    return ['download_id' => $this->download_id,'eta_time_sec' => $eta_time_sec];
}
```

//FFmpegController.php

```
public function generateVideo(Request $request_body)
{
        //Overlay file
        $transparent_img=Input::file('transparent_img');
        //Main file
        $video=Input::file('video');
        $output_file = $video_name;
        //Send in queue for ffmpeg overlay
        $job = new DownloadJob($video_name,$image,$output_file);
        $data = $this->dispatch($job);

        $dl_url = $job->getResponse();//Get response download_id and estimate time in second
       print_r($dl_url);
```

}

**Output**

I want to this answer in my output result.

```
   [
    'download_id':'NWM1ODAwNDU3NzkxOV92aWRlb19maWxlXzE1NDkyNzExMDkubXA0',
    'eta_time_sec':5
   ]
```

How can I get estimation time in seconds from **fps, bitrate or speed** but I have no clue..

Comment: I have the same problem. Because I want to get estimation time before running the command on FFmpeg.

Comment: Can you take help from JAVASCRIPT or it had to be via php?

Comment: I have to use PHP laravel.